# Slow response time every exactly 5 minutes

Tags: linux, cloud, response-time

We have a VPS hosted on Cloud Linux with a well known Web hosting company. We've always had a problem where exactly every 5 minutes, if you load a page from the website, you have to wait about 10 seconds before anything shows up.

Outside of this timespan, the website is very fast (less than 1 second).

I've asked the hosting support and they tried many things but nothing worked.

- We thought it was a memory issue so we upgraded and doubled our cores and ram to 2vCPU and 8 Gb Ram.
- We changed all my custom cron jobs to run at 6, 11, 16, etc instead of 5, 10 15.
- We even disabled all my cron job and just tried loading a static html page.
- One tech said it was Cloud Linux's cron jobs to gather statistics. He even changed those to run at 6, 11, 16, etc but the website is still unresponsive at every 5 min mark.

I've been talking to different tech support people and although they are helpful, still haven't fixed the problem.

If this was a Cloud Linux issue, every website running it would have this issue right?

Has anyone run into something similar?